# Is it safe to take address of an out of bounds vector index?

Tags: c++

In C++ Primer 5th edition it is mentioned that you can take the address of the non-existent element one past the last element of an *array* (so long as you don't de-reference it).

```
int arr[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int *e = &arr[10]; // 10 is 1 past the end.
```

For std::vector, does indexing into the vector with the [] operator and taking a reference have the same guarantee as array that it won't crash?

```
vector<int> vec(10, 0);
int *e = &vec[10];
```

I do understand there's little use-case for this since we have end() iterators and all that.

Comment: You're allowed to get an iterator or pointer to one beyond the last element (that is what the `end()` function returns), but you're not allowed to dereference it or using in any other way.

Comment: Not sure what exactly the standard has to say about `std::vector::operator[](size_t)`; cppreference.com mentions that "No bounds checking is performed." which would indicate that this is possible, but I wouldn't bet on the standard library implementation not putting an `assert` for checking against the size in the implementation logic... you should always be able to do `int* e = vec.data() + 10;` though...

Comment: @fabian take case to check `std::vector::size()` is non-zero 1st.

Comment: yep, visual studio's debug runtime will throw an exception on any out of bounds operator[] usage. Definitely undefined behaviour: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at

Comment: The `vec[10]` part of `int *e = &vec[10];` already has dereferenced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's undefined behaviour. The [definition](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.opt) of `vec[10]` is

```
*(vec.begin() + 10)
```

which is dereferencing an past-the-end iterator. [Furthermore](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.requirements.general#7)

> Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.

Comment: That said, `vec.data() + 10` is fine (although suspect for anything other than `vec.data() + vec.size()` to get you an “end” pointer.